# ZF Namespace Autoloader en Bootstrapping

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping, autoloader

I have a standard ZF structure

library
  -wil
   -Auth
    -Adapter.php

In this folder /libary/Wil/Auth/Adapter I have this class

based on http://www.zendcasts.com/logging-in-users-using-doctrine-and-zend_auth/2010/01/

class Wil_Auth_Adapter implements Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface
{

}

and in the application.ini I declare my autoloaderNamespaces[]="Wil"

I have nothing in the bootstrap to register it as a Helper Broker or anything.

My question is why does it work when i call it from a controller
like so $adapter = new Wil_Auth_Adapter()

It is probably clear that I don't understand the autoloader & resources & bootstrapping in ZF.

Where can I get a good explanation of the process?

Answer (score 0):

The autoloader automatically includes classes when they are first used. Resources are 'things' that the application uses such as a database connection, cache, autoloader. The bootstrap process sets up these resources. So these are three separate things but they are linked.

Your auth adapter is just a class, so it doesn't need any special setup via. brokers. The autoloader knows that a class called `Wil_Auth_Adapter` will live at `Wil/Auto/Adapter.php`, and it checks through the folders on the include_path (which include the library folder by default) for that class.

Comment: Thanks I am getting it now - also thanks to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931631/zf-include-path