# ZF Include path

Tags: zend-framework, require-once

Is it correct to require_once?
where and how would you put it include path?

Should it not be in a application.ini or bootstrap?

EXAMPLE:

```
require_once 'Zend/View/Helper/Abstract.php';
// @question - is this correct - where and
// how would you put it include path

class Zend_View_Helper_Translate extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Comment: My question to you... Is a view helper the solution you really need? Perhaps a plugin would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can avoid `require_once` calls almost entirely by appropriately using `Zend_Loader_Autoloader`. Of course, the key is "appropriate".

Typically, your `public/index.php` sets the `include_path` to be the `library` folder. Then, if you are using `Zend_Application`, the `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` is registered to find any [PSR-0 compliant classes](http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/) whose namespace prefixes have been registered using the `autoloadernamespaces` array in `application/configs/application.ini`.

The tricky part is for classes defined in files that don't "reside on the include_path", like models that appear in `application/models`, services that reside in `application/services`, etc. Even though the classes defined there tend to follow PSR-0 standards, the fact that the PSR-0 mapping occurs relative to a base **off** the include-path means that the system has to know the mapping between classname prefixes and base paths. This is where [resource autoloaders](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html) come in. These resource autoloaders are typically set up automatically in the application Bootstrap extending `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap` and module bootstraps that extend `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`.

View helpers are another example of classes that reside "off the include_path", perhaps in something like `application/views/helpers`. Since these are typically invoked in a view script using a short form `$this->someHelper($someParam)`, the system must be told how to generate the fully qualified classname from this short name. This is accomplished using `$view->addPrefixPath()` which maps namespace prefixes to filesystem locations. Again, the app-level and module level bootstrapping mechanism sets most of these up for you.

For libraries/classes that do not follow PSR-0 standards, you can create [custom autoloaders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820536/131824) and attach them (typically at Bootstrap) to the `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` singleton. This is the only place where you would have an explicit include/require.

tl;dr: With proper use of the existing ZF autoloader mechanism, you almost never need to have `include/require` statements in your own application code.

Comment: @Wil to boil down this great answer, lose the include statment and put the helper in the directory `application/views/helpers` or `modules/module/views/helpers` and it will work. In your view call the helper with `$this->Translate($someParam)`... Good Luck

Comment: This is the most comprehensive and concise answer. Did not expect so much Thank you! I am getting the hang of it but hard to find info this good.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped. And thanks to RockyFord for bottom-lining my typically over-expansive ramble. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

It is not correct in this case.

First off, please use Zend Tool. It will create the files you don't know how to create yourself. It will create the correct class names, extend them appropriately and `require_once` anything that might be needed.

Do not place `require_once` in the bootstrap. You want it to execute only when needed, not with every request.

As for the example you've provided, the correct version would be:

```
require_once "Zend/View/Interface.php";
class Zend_View_Helper_Foo extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
}
```

The class that is extended by the helper is autoloaded and putting it in `require_once` does nothing.

Comment: To the downvoter: any comment on WHY you think my answer is not useful?

Comment: Thanks see answer above. Finally getting there.